# Set up backend server for Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backend

I have a Rails 3.0 app hosted in Heroku. I would like to set up a different Rails server to run heavy back-end job (scanning user profiles, items and create recommendations and store them in a Redis database), so that it:

- will not clog my front-end server (i.e., if I run backend processes on the same front-end Rails server, it will take longer to response to users' requests etc.)
- allow me to have Rails classes and methods

My understanding is:

- adding more worker dynos won't separate front-end and back-end processes
- adding Whenever or Delayed_Job gems won't allow me to run on a separate backend server.

I think this situation should come up regularly for Rails. How should I go about this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What do you mean by "clog" a "front-end database"? You probably just have a regular database, and you should implement caching and thoughtful querying to avoid taxing it. Use Resque with Redis for tasks to avoid adding load to your SQL database.
- You can get access to "Rails classes and methods" in a rake task by loading the environment.  For example: `task :do_this => :environment { ... }`
- Every dyno is independent of every other dyno, whether they are web workers (available for HTTP requests) or worker dynos (for anything else).

You really just need to create rake tasks and add any additional services (like Clockwork) to your Procfile (Cedar stack only) to get this all running on Heroku.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually meant "clog my front-end server". What I meant was: if I need to run heavy jobs, such as indexing, matching objects on the same Rails front-end server, it will slow down my front-end server. This is the reason why I would like to set up an independent back-end server. Adding a worker dynos won't help here, because if a scheduled index job ran, it might take over all dynos. Now, for my backend server, I would like to access all Rails functionalities (i.e., I should be able to inherit from ActiveRecord etc.)

Comment: workers run in seperate processes to dynos - so they won't impact the front end. You would however have to consider your database as if that's shared between the two applications then that could be your bottleneck.

Comment: You aren't understanding the way Heroku works. A single process doesn't run across multiple dynos. A dyno runs a single instance of your application, regardless the context or task. Handling HTTP requests is one task that frameworks like Sinatra and Rails handle, but you can also run one-off Ruby scripts in separate dynos that are triggered via `heroku run ...`. There is no notion of a server with Heroku — they don't even play with hardware since they themselves run on top of AWS.